# Proportional editing not effecting some faces

Tags: modeling

I have a flat watchband that I want to curve.

I have selected a few vertices on the further end, activated proportional edit and moved these vertices. The majority of the band then flexes as expected but there are some faces that are acting very strangely and it seems they aren't really affected by the proportional edit as desired.

See red arrows in the attached images pointing to these areas.

[image]

I then tried achieving the bend using the simple deform modifier and it also resulted in a strange outer surface while the inner surface of the band is more or less correct.

[image]

The below image is what happends when i bend it a full 360 degrees.
[image]

Comment: Probably the topology is bad. You can't bend long faces, you have to break them by adding new verts and edges.